# AMDGPU Pro driver not working on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, radeon, gpu, amd-graphics

I recently upgraded to Xubuntu 16.04 and would like to install the AMDGPU Pro driver. The first time installing the driver, my secondary DVI monitor did not receive signal. The second attempt, not only did my secondary monitor not work, but one thread of my CPU got pegged to 100% and I experienced a massive system slowdown. My graphics card is an MSI Lightning R9 290X. Any help getting the driver working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AMDGPU-PRO doesn't yet work with 290X's or 390X's and probably won't until kernel 4.8/4.9.

Comment: According to AMD's website, the AMDGPU-PRO driver does work with both the 290X and 390X. http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: Huh... Well that's news to me: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMDGPU-SI-Almost-Ready - I'll have to give that a try.

Comment: Did you go through all the steps here?: https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

Comment: Yes, I followed the directions on AMD's site. The only difference is I did not use the command line to extract the file, I double clicked the .tar.xz file and used archive manager to extract it. On AMD's website, I did see a mention of installing LunarG Vulcan SDK along with the AMDGPU Pro driver. Could the absence of that be causing my issues?

Comment: Specifically the `video` group stuff? Probably not a LunarG issue. That is just for early Vulkan support for games that use it like Dota 2.

Comment: Yes, I did add myself to the video group.